# Why does the conductivity increase during an antiferromagnetic - ferromagnetic phase transition?

Tags: electrical-resistance, phase-transition, ferromagnetism

We're increasing the temperature of a sample of thin film FeRh which exhibits such a phase transition at approx. 350 K, at which the resistivity that we measure drops by about 40%. We assume that the magnetisation that appears at the transition temperature is affecting the number of conduction electrons but we aren't able to find any sources online to help validate or quantify our hypothesis. Any help or direction on this matter would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the number of electrons does not change, but the mean free path.

Conductivity also changes at Curie temperatures. There is less spin scattering in the ferromagnetically ordered case. This is also the explanation of the giant magnetoresistance in multilayers (2007 Nobelprize, Fert and Grünberg).